# Changing default JavaScript editor for iOS simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator, sublimetext3, webstorm

I am using react-native to develope an iOS app. When I click on an `error` on the iOS simulator, it opens `Sublime Text` as the editor.

Is there a way to change the behaviour so it opens the error file in another IDE(webstorm)?

I've tried **deleting Sublime Text** or changing the file association in **Get Info**, none of them worked.

Answer (score 9):

You should add an environment variable named `REACT_EDITOR` in your profile file and set it to your IDE of choice. I work with zshell so I added the following line to my `.zshrc` file

`export REACT_EDITOR="/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea"`

Don't forget to close all of your terminal windows and restart the react-native packager before you try it.

Comment: Perfect! This was bugging the hell out of me :)

Comment: @ofird I'm trying to setup intellij as editor as you do though when itellij opens it says it "Cannot Find File" and the project is open + the file path is correct. Does it still work for you? I'm using intellij 2017.2

Comment: Any idea how to set `REACT_EDITOR` to PhpStorm ?

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. You can find up to date solution for 2022 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73351531/5700121).