# How to set React_Editor to PhpStorm so that when you click on the error it jumps to the code?

Tags: react-native, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm using `PhpStorm` in Mac to code and i want to debug my errors. I have a message in my terminal to set the editor for React Native tools.

```
    PRO TIP 
  When you see Red Box with stack trace, you can click any 
  stack frame to jump to the source file. The packager will launch your 
  editor of choice. It will first look at REACT_EDITOR environment 
  variable, then at EDITOR.
  To set it up, you can add something like 
  export REACT_EDITOR=atom to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc depending on 
  which shell you use.
```

I've added these lines to ~/.bashrc but nothing happened when i click on the error :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/pstorm
export REACT_EDITOR=pstorm
```

How can i set correctly `REACT_EDITOR` to `PhpStorm` so that when i click on the error it jumps to my code?

Comment: does PhpStorm start when you run `pstorm` in terminal? I'd suggest re-creating the command line launcher via **Tools -> Create Command line launcher** and then specifying the launcher name as `REACT_EDITOR` value

Comment: Yes PhpStrom starts when i run `pstorm` in the terminal. The way i did to edit the `~/.bashrc`  is it correct or what should i do?

Comment: looks OK... does it work if you start PhpStorm from the terminal?

Comment: Yes PhpStrom starts when i run pstorm in the terminal. But the problem is when i click on the error in the simulator it doesn't open the file where the error occurred

Comment: i.e. PhpStorm starts when you click a link, but the file is not opened? Or?

Answer (score 3):

**UPD for webstorm 2023.1**

Just add to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zprofile`.

```
export REACT_EDITOR="webstorm"
export PATH="/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"
```

**Original answer for previous version of webstorm.**

For mac os you need to add to `~/.bashrc` or `.zprofile`:

`Add export REACT_EDITOR="webstorm"` or `pstorm`

Don't forget to close all of your terminal windows and restart the react-native packager before you try it.

Create a shortcut to open WebStorm:

1. Open WebStorm
2. Press `⇧` twice to open the search window
3. Type “Create Command Line Launcher…” and press Enter
4. Click OK
   [image]

That's it.

`/usr/local/bin` should be in the PATH environment variable by default. You should be able to run webstorm from anywhere in the shell. Run `webstorm /usr/local/bin/webstorm` to test the command.

You can find a code which opens editors [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v5.0.1/packages/react-dev-utils/launchEditor.js) or in your project `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/build/launchEditor.js`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating symlink.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm /usr/local/bin/webstorm
```

Comment: in my case running webstorm from a link gives an error as `/Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/MacOS/webstorm` requires its modules from `/usr/local/bin/Contents` and so on